# How to get Textbox text and image from XLS excel sheet in Python?

Tags: python, excel

I want to get textbox's text and images from the Excel sheet.
Previously I was using win32com to scrape and it was working perfectly fine for XLS and XLSX format.

But problem now is on my client server, it cant install Excel program which means win32com couldn't be run. So is there any way I can do it without the win32com ?

Here is my xls example file: [XLS file](https://file.gd/RWxlU2)

Here is the
win32com code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os
import pywintypes
import base64
from PIL import ImageGrab
from io import BytesIO


excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = False
excel_file = "C:\\pythonScrape\\ewf.xls"
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(excel_file)
ws = wb.Sheets('Sheet1')  # Set appropriate sheet name 

for shp in ws.Shapes:
    print(f"Shape Type: '{shp.Type}'")
    print(f"Shape Name: '{shp.Name}'")

    if shp.Type == 17:  #  17 = textbox
        print(f"Text Box '{shp.Name}' text: '{shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text}'")
        print('-------------------------\n')
    elif shp.Type == 6:  # 6 = Group
        print('\n=========================')
        for grp in shp.GroupItems:
            print(f"Group Shape Type: '{grp.Type}'")
            print(f"Group Shape Name: '{grp.Name}'")
            if grp.Type == 17:
                print(f"Grouped Text Box '{grp.Name}' text: '{grp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text}'")
                print('-------------------------\n')
            elif grp.Type == 11:  # 11 = image
                try:
                    # Copy the image to the clipboard
                    grp.Copy()
                    image = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
                    if image:
                        # Convert the image to base64
                        buffered = BytesIO()
                        image.save(buffered, format="PNG")
                        image_base64 = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
                        print(f"Base64-encoded image '{grp.Name}':")
                        print(image_base64)
                        print('-------------------------\n')
                except pywintypes.com_error as e:
                    print(f"Error copying image: {e}")
    elif shp.Type == 11:  # Type 11 is an image
        try:
            # Copy the image 
            shp.Copy()
            image = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
            if image:
                # Convert the image to base64
                buffered = BytesIO()
                image.save(buffered, format="PNG")
                image_base64 = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
                print(f"Base64-encoded image '{shp.Name}':")
                print(image_base64)
                print('-------------------------\n')
        except pywintypes.com_error as e:
            print(f"Error copying image: {e}")

excel.Quit()
```

I tried to used unzip to decompress the XLS file and unfortunately it doesn't work and only able to scrape some text. (But it worked perfectly fine for XLSX format).

Unzip code:

```
import zipfile as z

class Sheet(str):
    @property
    def shapes(this):
        s = z.ZipFile(this)
        #p='xl/drawings/drawing1.xml'  # shapes path, *.xlsx default
        p='drs/shapexml.xml'  # shapes path, *.xls default
        return XML(s.read(p))


class XML(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = str(value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.value[i]

    def tag_content(self, tag):
        return [XML(i) for i in self.value.split(tag)[1::2]]

    @property
    def text(self):
        t = self.tag_content('xdr:txBody')  # list of XML codes, each containing a seperate textboxes, messy (with extra xml that is)
        l = [i.tag_content('a:p>') for i in t]  # split into sublists by line breaks (inside the textbox), messy
        w = [[[h[1:-2] for h in i.tag_content('a:t')] if i else ['\n'] for i in j] for j in l]  # clean into sublists by cell-by-cell basis (and mind empty lines)
        l = [[''.join(i) for i in j] for j in w]  #  join lines overlapping multiple cells into one sublist
        return ['\n'.join(j) for j in l]  #  join sublists of lines into strings seperated by newline char
    
print(Sheet(r'C:\pythonScrape\ewf.xls').shapes.text)
```

Comment: Well isn't that annoying... An 'xls' file is a proprietary binary file whereas a 'xlsx' file is a bunch of zipped 'XML' files. So unzipping an 'xlsx' file and reading the data directly from the XML is possible but not an option with with the 'xls' files. Given there is not much option for reading textboxes from 'xls' files and you have your option for 'xlsx' files the best course would seem to be to convert the 'xls' to 'xlsx'. I don't know your exact situation, maybe converting the files before they are copied to the client server is possible or they may need to be converted on the same PC.

Comment: There are a few 'xls' to 'xlsx' converters. Options using python are limited however, and whatever is available may drop elements like textboxes making the conversion useless. There are other purpose built options that can be executed as command line that may suit your purposes.

Comment: Personally I'd use LibreOffice. This is free software which can convert pretty much any Office format from one type to another. The executable 'soffice' is compatible with Windows and Linux and will convert 'xls' to 'xlsx' with a single line command preserving all elements and data in the file. However obviously being a client server it may not be allowed to install/use this software.

Comment: @moken Thank you for your active response on my questions, after more research I decided to use a library called [Aspose](https://blog.aspose.com/cells/convert-xls-to-xlsx-in-python/)  With this library it able to convert xls to xlsx without format change or missing element in the excel sheet